pyspark - avoiding multiple alias of the table in the join condition
This is the piece of code that's giving correct output but performancewise is very worst.
Is there a way where 'modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map' table used only once and get the same result?
postx_fact = spark.sql(f"""select panelist_id,tm_dim_key_week,synd_venue_dim_key, fact_bkey, derived_item_net_amount, derived_item_quantity,
                               case 
                                when upper(it_co.sub_cat_code) like '%GBY%' then co_synd_item_dim_key
                                when synd.item_dim_key > 0 and synd.map_cw_subcategory is null then synd.item_dim_key 
                                when de.item_dim_key > 0 and de.map_cw_subcategory is null then de.item_dim_key 
                                when bc_ws.item_dim_key > 0 and bc_ws.map_cw_subcategory is null then bc_ws.item_dim_key 
                                when pos_wkly.item_dim_key > 0 and pos_wkly.map_cw_subcategory is null then pos_wkly.item_dim_key 
                                when pos_dly.item_dim_key > 0 and pos_dly.map_cw_subcategory is null then pos_dly.item_dim_key 
                                when it_co.item_dim_key is not null and not (vn.rp_outlet='CONVENIENCE' and upper(nvl(fct.custom_col2,'NO'))='CAN/BOTTLE') 
                                then it_co.item_dim_key
                                when se.item_dim_key > 0 and se.map_cw_subcategory is null then se.item_dim_key   
                                else 922481888 
                                end as item_dim_key_join_column 
                                from {MAIN_SCHEMA2}.postx_fact_merge_with_ecomm_with_co fct
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.it_co_eal_v3 it_co on it_co.item_dim_key = fct.co_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map synd on synd.item_dim_key = fct.synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map de on de.item_dim_key = fct.de_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map bc_ws on bc_ws.item_dim_key = fct.bc_ws_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map pos_wkly on pos_wkly.item_dim_key = fct.pos_wkly_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map pos_dly on pos_dly.item_dim_key = fct.pos_dly_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map se on se.item_dim_key = fct.se_synd_item_dim_key
                                left outer join {TARGET_SCHEMA}.cmpltwlt_vn_eal_mstr vn on vn.venue_dim_key = fct.synd_venue_dim_Key where tm_dim_key_week between {START_WEEK} AND {END_WEEK}""")

I have tried using explode and collect list but not sure how to develop the case statment like the original one and also not sure how to avoid double counting in fact values
select panelist_id,tm_dim_key_week,synd_venue_dim_key, fact_bkey, derived_item_net_amount, derived_item_quantity,co_synd_item_dim_key,collect_list(exp_temp_item_dim_keys) as collect_exp_temp_item_dim_keys,collect_list(item_dim_key) as coalesce_item_dim_key,collect_list(item_dim_key)[5] as se_synd_item_dim_key_join_col from 
                               (select *
               from (select panelist_id,tm_dim_key_week,synd_venue_dim_key, fact_bkey, derived_item_net_amount, derived_item_quantity,co_synd_item_dim_key,array(synd_item_dim_key,de_synd_item_dim_key,bc_ws_synd_item_dim_key,pos_wkly_synd_item_dim_key,pos_dly_synd_item_dim_key,se_synd_item_dim_key) as temp_item_dim_keys, explode(array(synd_item_dim_key,de_synd_item_dim_key,bc_ws_synd_item_dim_key,pos_wkly_synd_item_dim_key,pos_dly_synd_item_dim_key,se_synd_item_dim_key)) as exp_temp_item_dim_keys 
                               from {MAIN_SCHEMA2}.postx_fact_merge_with_ecomm_with_co where tm_dim_key_week between {START_WEEK} AND {END_WEEK}) fct 
              left outer join (select item_dim_key  from {TARGET_SCHEMA}.modelled_nbd_item_sub_cat_map where map_cw_subcategory is null ) sub_cat_map
              on fct.exp_temp_item_dim_keys = sub_cat_map.item_dim_key) a group by panelist_id,tm_dim_key_week,synd_venue_dim_key, fact_bkey, derived_item_net_amount, derived_item_quantity,co_synd_item_dim_key

